# How do I set a Global Variable in Postman with a value from one of the Request Header?

Tags: javascript, postman

I am sending a request via Postman that requires Basic Auth. 
I want to save the value of the basic auth in a variable so i will be able to use it again.

In the request I am sending I'm providing user name and password (basic), and it is translated into authorization header.
i want to take the value sent in the request header, and save it.

**how can i take the value from the request header and place in a env variable, all in Test Script?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the **test**

You can write something like that after creating `global variable` you can go to your `service` that **provides you the value** and add the test and set the result in the `global variable`.

For example for me the `login service` provides me a `token` so after testing and getting the `new token` i set this in `the global variable token`

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
if (jsonData && jsonData.result && jsonData.result.session) {
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", jsonData.result.session.token);
}
```

[image]

Comment: this is how to configure it in variable, but how can i take it from the request header?

Comment: sorry i miss understood so now this is the answer for your question

Comment: i need to derive the value from a **request header**.

could you please help me write the script like you send, but to take the value from the request header?

Comment: you can just do the same testing script in the Auth service and set the value returned in a global variable i cannot do more i have no access to your stuff